# Como limpar a folha de estilos (CSS) do Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Possuo um site que utiliza Bootstrap, porém, nesse site há muitas **classes** e **id's** que eu não utilizo. Isso faz com que meu site fique muito **pesado** a toa.

O que eu posso fazer para excluir todas essas classes e id's inúteis?

Devo fazer manualmente? (o que estou pensando em fazer)

Ou existe alguma ferramenta que faz esse trabalho por mim? (não sei se existe)

Answer (score 5):

Tu tem certeza de que *este* é mesmo o motivo do teu site estar pesado? Pergunto porque considero o Bootstrap muito leve.

---

Quanto a sua pergunta: **Sim**, é perfeitamente possível.

Isso é fornecido por alguns frameworks. No caso específico do Bootstrap vá até *http://getbootstrap.com/customize/* e selecione apenas oque tu pretende usar. Há outras customizações possíveis também.

Já ouvi de gente deletando funções não utilizadas do código fonte do jQuery, porém não recomendo pois isso pode quebrar algum plugin. Neste caso não há ferramenta automatizada, tu teria que fazer manualmente mesmo.

---

Mas eu recomendo tu não se preocupar muito com isso, pois acho muito improvável que o Bootstrap/jQuery sejam o gargalo de desempenho do teu site. O erro mais comum é abusar do Javascript.

Ao invés disso procure dicas como as abaixo:

- *[Como perder peso no browser](http://browserdiet.com/pt/)*
- *[Como melhorar o desempenho de arquivos estáticos de um site?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14690/como-melhorar-o-desempenho-de-arquivos-estaticos-de-um-site)*
- *[jQuery: dicas de otimização e performance](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14690/como-melhorar-o-desempenho-de-arquivos-estaticos-de-um-site)*

Comment: Outra boa ferramenta para teste de performance de um site é o [PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/) do Google.