# Sobre HREF e SRC, enfim, quais as diferenças de aplicação?

Tags: html

Pelo que andei lendo, `HREF` serve para apontar para algo externo(fora da página) que o usuário requisitar, ou que a página que o contêm necessitar usa-lo(no caso das folhas de estilo).

Ou seja, no caso das folhas de estilo, quando apontado com `HREF` o navegador não pausa a renderização ou carregamento DOM para aplicar a folha de estilo se a mesma não for usada em algum momento.

Já o `SRC` ele pausa a renderização para despejar o conteúdo do arquivo chamado.

Sobre isso que comentei acima, vos pergunto:

- Se possuo uma função que dá um `append` de uma estrutura em HTML de uma
  *Newsletter* por exemplo, seria mais eficiente chamar a folha de estilo
  que faz o "design" dessa *Newsletter* por `HREF`?

Já que no primeiro momento da entrada do usuário no site, não há uso dessa folha, que       posteriormente só será usada caso o usuário requisita-se(clica-se em     um botão/link para abrir então a
*Newsletter*), sendo assim.. Não haveria    a necessidade de pausar a renderização para despejar o CSS que em    primeiro momento não vai ser utilizada..

Ficou pouco confuso?! Se eu estiver confundindo alguma coisa, me digam!

---

Vi esta discussão aqui:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395359/difference-between-src-and-href

E até então desconhecia que as folhas de estilos podiam ser chamadas com o atributo HREF, sempre usei SRC e nunca conheci bem a diferença de aplicação para ambas.

Comment: Pelo pouco que entendi da pergunta linkada, é o *parse* (leitura, análise sintática) da página que é interrompida quando um script usa `src`, enquanto com um link usando `href` isso não acontece. O **processamento** em si pode parar sim. Além disso, o elemento `img` também utiliza o `src`, mas nesse caso nem o *parsing* nem o processamento param (i.e. a página é exibida primeiro sem a imagem, e depois com). Não me parece haver uma regra geral para todos os casos. Ou você se refere especificamente a folhas de estilo?

Comment: "Mais eficiente" em relação a que? A um CSS inline que viria com o append?

Comment: S[ó um comentário de que que HREF também serve para ligações internas à própria página que o definiu, atribuindo à ele um ID de algum elemento existente no DOM.

Comment: -BrunoAugusto, no caso de ancoras né? 
@bfavaretto, a ideia é de ser mais eficiente em questão a desempenho, experiência do usuário(página ser mais rápida no carregamento). Pois, como a folha de estilo da Newsletter(news.css por exemplo) só vai ser usado se/caso o usuário abri-se de fato o link/botão da Newsletter(que por sua vez o script daria um append com a estrutura HTML), logo em primeiro momento não precisaria ter a necessidade da página despejar o CSS na página, assim não atrapalharia o parsing da página.
Para pequenas aplicações vejo mínimos benefícios,.. Mas para grandes, só testando?

Comment: Será essa uma má prática? menos segura, podendo comprometer não o desempenho e sim algo mais importante, como alguma função da página, por algum gargalo que possa ocorrer?

Comment: É que eu não entendi a pergunta. Você diz que sempre usou `src`... Para carregar CSS? Como já disse o elias na resposta dele, link com src não é válido.

Comment: Entendido, então `<style>` se faz uso do atributo HREF ao invés de SRC(não existindo cenário para uso deste), já imagens fazem uso de SRC, assim como `<script>` faz uso deste. Isso porquê se faz necessário despejar o conteúdo no HTML, no caso da imagem carrega-la para o documento, e no caso do script ser semelhante a despejar o código dentro das tags `<script></script>`..
Logo, HREF faz uma relação de algo externo, fora do documento, com algo do documento, e com isso, quando requisitado, ele acaba por carregar os estilos(no caso de .css) e sim pausar a renderização para aplicação destes.

Comment: Logo, HREF não atrapalha no parsing, apenas na renderização se o mesmo for requisitado(no caso das folhas de estilo).
Então, se eu chamar a folha de estilo por `@import`, o que, pelo que li, seria semelhante a despejar o conteúdo nas tags estilos(importar de fato), vai causar a pausa no parsing da página para aplicação dos estilos, está certo isso que estou afirmando?

Comment: Ou seja, @import vai causar um atraso no parsing, para o carregamento da folha de estilo, que foi importada, mesmo que ela não fosse requisitada pela DOM? Me descupem se eu estiver viajando em algum conceito!!

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus Eu acho que o `@import` causa uma requisição síncrona. Portanto ficaria com o `<link href...>` no documento principal, como o elias já sugeriu.

Comment: achei o título ambíguo pois não diz que é sobre as folhas de estilo css.. Dá a entender que se refere ao geral como <a> e <img>..

Answer (score 5):

É bem possível que a maneira mais eficiente seja importar todo o CSS necessário já no HEAD do html, antes de fazer qualquer atualização dinâmica via JavaScript: se a atulização for via Ajax você poupa uma requisição (ou payload, no caso do CSS embutido no HTML).

Tendo dito isto, como qualquer questão de eficiência, o único jeito de saber realmente é medindo para o seu caso. Mas eu não me preocuparia em otimizar isso enquanto não for um gargalo de desempenho.

Se você está tendo problemas de desempenho, [use as ferramentas do seu browser para verificar onde está o gargalo](https://fernandofreela.wordpress.com/2013/09/18/chrome-devtools/) -- os problemas mais comuns estão relacionados a rede (número de requisições, tamanho dos arquivos, etc). Outra ferramenta útil é o [PageSpeed](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pagespeed-insights-by-goo/gplegfbjlmmehdoakndmohflojccocli?hl=en), que faz uma análise da sua página e provê algum feedback do que você pode fazer para melhorá-la.

**Nota:** Sobre `href` vs `src`, já foi mencionado nos comentários, mas você usa `href` com [`<link>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link) e `src` com `<script>` (e `<img>`): `src` não é um atributo válido para [`<link>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link).

### Ler mais:

- [Como melhorar o desempenho de arquivos estáticos de um site?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14690/como-melhorar-o-desempenho-de-arquivos-est%C3%A1ticos-de-um-site/14966#14966)
- [PageSpeed Rules and Recommendation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/page-speed-rules-and-recommendations) (em inglês)
- [Optimize CSS delivery](http://www.feedthebot.com/pagespeed/optimize-css-delivery.html) (em inglês)

Comment: Interessante, tem tantas coisas para se preocupar(minificação,diminuir nr. de requisições,sprites em imagens,compressão das imagens,) que isso que citei seria o último e opcional preocupação que deve se ter..
Acredito, pensando melhor, que o que comentei talvez não seja uma boa prática, ou melhor, uma prática menos "segura" podendo até comprometer a experiência do usuário..