# CSS Media Queries (várias declarações seguidas)

Tags: css, layout-responsivo, media-queries

Olá, quero saber se é possível obter um solução mais limpa e mais compacta do seguinte CSS.

```
    @media screen and (min-width: 630px) {
        .tab ul.login{
            right: 29%;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 760px) {
        .tab ul.login{
            right: 27%;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 830px) {
        .tab ul.login{
            right: 30%;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 990px) {
        .tab ul.login{
            right: 21%;
        }
    }


    @media screen and (min-width: 1030px) {
        .tab ul.login{
            right: 24%;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1160px) {
        .tab ul.login{
            right: 25%;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
        .tab ul.login{
            right: 19%;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1300px) {
        .tab ul.login{
            right: 21%;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1400px) {
        .tab ul.login{
            right: 24.5%;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1560px) {
        .tab ul.login{
            right: 1%;
        }
    }

@media screen and (min-width: 1760px) {
    .tab ul.login{
        right: 7%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não existe uma regra padrão, e essa resposta pode até ser baseada em opinião.
Mas você pode separar em arquivos diferentes e utilizar a regra da media no [atributo `media` da tag `link`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_media.asp):

```
<link href="style-min-default.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="style-min-630.css" media="screen and (min-width: 630px)" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="style-min-760.css" media="screen and (min-width: 760px)" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="style-min-830.css" media="screen and (min-width: 830px)" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="style-min-990.css" media="screen and (min-width: 990px)" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="style-min-1030.css" media="screen and (min-width: 1030px)" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="style-min-1160.css" media="screen and (min-width: 1160px)" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="style-min-1200.css" media="screen and (min-width: 1200px)" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="style-min-1300.css" media="screen and (min-width: 1300px)" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="style-min-1400.css" media="screen and (min-width: 1400px)" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="style-min-1560.css" media="screen and (min-width: 1560px)" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="style-min-1760.css" media="screen and (min-width: 1760px)" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Arquivos:

```
// style-min-630.css
.tab ul.login{
  right: 29%;
}

// style-min-760.css
.tab ul.login{
  right: 27%;
}

// style-min-830.css
.tab ul.login{
  right: 30%;
}

// style-min-990.css
.tab ul.login{
  right: 21%;
}

// style-min-1030.css
.tab ul.login{
  right: 24%;
}

// style-min-1160.css
.tab ul.login{
  right: 25%;
}

// style-min-1200.css
.tab ul.login{
  right: 19%;
}

// style-min-1300.css
.tab ul.login{
  right: 21%;
}

// style-min-1400.css
.tab ul.login{
  right: 24.5%;
}

// style-min-1560.css
.tab ul.login{
  right: 1%;
}

// style-min-1760.css
.tab ul.login{
  right: 7%;
}
```

**Lembrando que esse código não está visando performance, para esse propósito [o melhor é compactar tudo em um único arquivo minificado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/14700/8493).**

Com essa estrutura, você tem um ambiente de desenvolvimento organizado, mas pro usuário final fica um pouco pesado, então uma boa solução pra isso seria utilizar um pre-processador como [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) utilizando o plugin [clean-css](https://github.com/less/less-plugin-clean-css) que possibilita mesclar vários arquivos e compacta-los ao mesmo tempo, tendo assim apenas um arquivo CSS:

```
// style.min.less
@import url("style-min-630.less");
@import url("style-min-760.less");
@import url("style-min-830.less");
@import url("style-min-990.less");
@import url("style-min-1030.less");
@import url("style-min-1160.less");
@import url("style-min-1200.less");
@import url("style-min-1300.less");
@import url("style-min-1400.less");
@import url("style-min-1560.less");
@import url("style-min-1760.less");
```

Processe o arquivo: (via linha de comando)

```
lessc style.min.less > style.min.css --clean-css="--s1 --advanced --compatibility=ie8"
```

E use-o em produção

```
<link href="style.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Acho que a melhor solução será "minificar" o código mesmo

Comment: @lazyFox a melhor solução mesmo é usar um preprocessador como less e importar todos os arquivos e processa-lo minificando. ;)

Comment: @lazyFox complementei a resposta, assim você pode usar das duas maneiras, separado para o desenvolvimento e compactado para usuário final.