# Qual a melhor forma de fazer @Media para obter responsividade

Tags: html5, css3, front-end

Eu estava lendo/pesquisando de como aplicar responsividade em sites para qualquer tipo de plataforma e encontrei esse post feito aqui mesmo na **Stack** [@Media](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/71996/css-media-queries-v%C3%A1rias-declara%C3%A7%C3%B5es-seguidas)

Feito isso me abriu algumas dúvidas:

1. O conteudo do link ainda é valido? Eu realmente tenho que criar uma média para cada tipo de resolução?
2. Para poder aplicar as Media Querie de forma correta eu tenho que
   passar todas as propriedades novamente?

Exemplo:

Tenho essa propriedade CSS

```
.avatar::after {
    opacity: 0;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f040";
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    top: 3px;
    left: 4px;
    width: 144px;
    height: 140px;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 350ms ease-in-out;
}
```

E caso queria aplicar alguma média tenha que fazer assim (obviamente alterando os valores até ficar dinâmico)

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
    .avatar::after {
        opacity: 0;
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        content: "\f040";
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 2.5rem;
        position: absolute;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        top: 3px;
        left: 4px;
        width: 144px;
        height: 140px;
        z-index: 2;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        border-radius: 50%;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: 350ms ease-in-out;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As informações ainda são válidas no link sim, só acho um pouco de exagero para cada diferença de 100px por exemplo, fazer um media query.
Veja as resoluções do `bootstrap` por exemplo que são muito bem definidas e aceitas: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/

Apenas para referência, caso o link não esteja um dia disponível:

> Extra small devices Phones (<768px)
>   Small devices Tablets (≥768px)
>   Medium devices Desktops (≥992px)
>   Large devices Desktops (≥1200px)

E para o caso de colunas ou grid, já existe o `bootstrap` e outros como o `material` que já tem isso.

Sobre as propriedades, você só precisa definir o que vai mudar numa resolução específica.

Por exemplo, imagine que uma determinada classe deve ter a propriedade `display` como `block`, mas apenas numa resolução específica, deve ser `inline-block`. Nesse caso, basta sobrescrever a propriedade uma vez:

```
div.umaClasse {
   display: block
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    div.umaClasse {
       display: inline-block
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  /* aqui não preciso redefinir  div.umaClasse pois não vai mudar */
}
```